# How to create an alerting in Open Distro that warns about the event increase in Wazuh?

Tags: elasticsearch-opendistro, wazuh

For example, over 4000 events per day should have an email notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Open Distro, where no [CCS](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security/access-control/cross-cluster-search/) is being used and want to create an email notification for over 4000 events in a day, find below the high level steps:

1. Click on Alerting on the left menu
2. Click on Destinations tab and Add destination, this will be an [Email as a destination](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/monitors/#email-as-a-destination), enter a valid email and the smtp configuration under Manage Senders, then select it under Sender, add a recipient email under Recipients
3. Create a [Monitor](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/monitors/#create-monitors): Under **Method of definition** you can select `Define using visual graph`, under **Index** enter `wazuh-alerts*` (this will select all events that you visualize under Wazuh>Modules>Security Events), under **Time field** you can select `@timestamp`. Leave the `WHEN Count()`, `OVER all documents` and `WHERE all fields are included` as default, in option `FOR THE LAST …` select for the last `24 hours`. Finally select the frequency under **Monitor Schedule** as `Daily` and the time when you want this to run, alternatively you can select `By interval` and run it Every `1 Days`, click on Create
4. With the Monitor created you will have to create a [trigger](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/monitors/#create-triggers), in **trigger condition** enter `IS ABOVE 4,000`. Under **Configure actions** select the Destination created in step 2, then the Message subject you would like the recipient to receive and you can leave the Message by default, it uses [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) if you would like to edit it, you can send a test message to check if the Destination and smtp is configured correctly. Click on Create
5. Last step is to enable your monitor in case it was not enabled when created, select it from Monitors tab and click on Actions>Enable

I hope you are able to configure it, let me know!

Comment: I created but its not being triggered, I don't know why. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Are you getting to the specific condition for the alert to be triggered? does it show any error? make sure the monitor is enabled

Comment: Yes, I put that for over 4,000 events the alert is generated and the daily average is 5,000 events. I put 4,000 to take the test. No errors are appearing, and the monitor is active to run every day at the same time.